# how to find link address related to project file in .net

Tags: c#, .net, redirect

In my .net project, I want to create a button on a web page and when clicking on it, a new window will open. I added a web form to the same branch with the current webpage (named: webname).

In current webpage I add:

```
  //Open new form:
       Response.Redirect("~/webname.aspx");
```

But when I run, it open a link on new window, but cannot find this new webpage.
Error:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

I really don't know how to point to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

```
Response.Redirect("webname.aspx");
```

since, the web form located in the same branch as you said.

another option is to use HTML as follow

```
<a href="webname.aspx" runat="server" target="_blank">My Page</a>
```

As you can see the HTML attribute **target="_blank"** tells browser to open new window for you.

Good luck.

Comment: the webpage will have this address: http://localhost:61873/desktopdefault.aspx?tabindex=2&tabid=15. The new webpage that it open will have this address: http://localhost:61873/webname.aspx. And it said that it cannot be found. I don't know how could one file in the project be linked with that link address.

Comment: Try always use HTML anchor tags to direct users unless you're trying to post data to the server. Good Luck